# How would I get the game to restart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was making a gameover screen and it included a restart button. I made the restart button if pressed to reset the base variables to False and 0 but instead of restarting the game just exits. I don't know if the variable cannot be set to true again, or if there is a code statement that restarts everything including variables. Any suggestions?
All the code is in def DrawGameOver.

```
def DrawGameOver():
    win.blit (Overscreen, (0, 0))
    button1 = pygame.Rect(200, 400, 100, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, [255, 0, 0], button1)
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_pos = event.pos
        if button1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            player.gameover = False
            player.run = True
            player.grassdamage = 0
            player.damage1 = False
            player.damage2 = False
            player.damage3 = False
            player.damage4 = False
            player.damage5 = False
            player.damage6 = False
            player.damage7 = False
            player.damage8 = False
            player.score = 0
            time_now = 0
    Text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Restart?", Text)
    TextRect.center = ((250), (425))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()

while player.gameover:
    clock.tick (60)
    print (player.run, player.gameover)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            player.gameover = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                player.gameover = False
    DrawGameOver()
```

Comment: *if there is a code statement that restarts everything* – it's called a loop. You can use a `for` loop or a `while` loop.

Comment: There is too much code here for Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to be much smaller, but still with the same problem.

Comment: every class should have method `reset()` so you could use it when you start new game.

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - ie. `class Player()`, `class Car1` - and `lower_case_names` for variables and functions - ie. `def draw_game_over()`. It helps to recognize class in code - ie. `player = Player()`. Many IDEs know this rule and they use different color for classes. even Stackoverflow uses different color for classes `Surface`, `Clock`, `Font`

Comment: you could use loop like `while True: if not intro(): break ; if not game(): break ;  if not gameover(): break`. It runs three elements in loop so after gameover it start game again. If any element returns `False` then it exit loop and it ends program.

Answer (score 1):

You could use loop like this

```
 while True: 
      intro()
      menu()
      game()
      gameover()
```

and it should run game again and again

If functions will return `False` when you want to end game then you can do

```
 while True: 
      if not intro():
         break
      if not menu():
         break
      if not game():
         break
      if not gameover():
         break
```